# Laravel 4 subdirectory controller doesn't load Input class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel and having trouble with subdirectories.
I want to make an admin folder inside the controllers folder and so far it's working. but when I try to use Laravel's Input class it says that it couldn't find it.

My routes:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=> 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'), function() {

   Route::resource('/users','Admin\\UsersController');
   Route::resource('/products','Admin\\ProductsController');
   Route::resource('/categories','Admin\\CategoriesController');
   Route::resource('/orders','Admin\\OrdersController');
   Route::resource('/reviews','Admin\\ReviewsController');

});
```

The Products Controller:

```
 <?php namespace admin;

    class ProductsController extends \BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'master';
        /**
     * Instantiate a new ProductsController instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth.admin');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * GET /products
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $input = Input::all(); //here is where it finds the error
```

And the composer.json autoload:

```
"autoload": {

        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers/",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/controllers/Admin"
        ]
    },
```

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I have also tried to use Input (and \Input) and it returned the "Class 'Facade' not found" error, and when I tried:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Input;
```

It still did not work.

**Edit 2:**

Now using:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

and returning the same error.

**Edit 3:**
Did the modifications suggested by @ChristopherRathgeb and now it's not finding the products model.

**Answer:**

After doing the modifications suggested by @ChristopherRathgeb and adding \ to the View and Input classes(example `$input = \Input:all();`) it worked! And now to redirect to these controller with the action method I just used action(admin\ProductsController) and it worked!

My thanks to all who helped!

Comment: It seems weird that you would need to `use` Input or Facade as they should be automatically registered as soon as the app is started. Did you `composer dump-autoload` after moving the controllers into the subdirectory?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Don't Panic , and i dit run `composer dump-autoload` successfully, but it's still not working (and driving me crazy haha)

Comment: Try removing the `Admin\\\` portion from the route. After doing composer dump-autoload, the autoloader should be able to get the controllers without needing to specify the subdirectory.

Comment: I did that and got a "Class ProductsController does not exist" error

Comment: If you look at the composer/autoload_classmap.php, does it have your controller files listed in the proper location?

Comment: It does. `'AdminController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/AdminController.php',
    'Admin\\CategoriesController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/admin/CategoriesController.php',
    'Admin\\OrdersController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/admin/OrdersController.php',
    'Admin\\ReviewsController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/admin/ReviewsController.php',
    'Admin\\UsersController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/admin/UsersController.php',
    'Admin\\ProductsController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/admin/ProductsController.php',`

Comment: Sorry I haven't been able to help. As far as I can tell I have created the same setup you have here and it works with either `use Input;` or `use \\Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Input;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off you can use a route group based on the namespace:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'admin','prefix'=> 'admin', 'before' => 'auth.admin'],function() {
   Route::resource('/users','UsersController');
   Route::resource('/products','ProductsController');
   Route::resource('/categories','CategoriesController');
   Route::resource('/orders','OrdersController');
   Route::resource('/reviews','ReviewsController');
});
```

Next your issue with input is that you need to include the Input facade:

Remove this:

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Input;
```

and Add the following to the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

NOTE: This answer uses php 5.4 array syntax.  If you are still using php 5.3 swap out the [] for array().

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have followed you suggestion but i still get the "Class 'Facade' not found" error. :/

Comment: Do you have any sample code that shows your usage of Facade?  I do not know how you would be using it in your controller like this.  Typically the Facade class is subclassed.

Comment: sorry but I don't think i have any sample code of me using Facade, i actually don't even know what it is... If you could be more especific about the file you would like to have i look i'd be glad to post it!

Comment: `$input = Input::all();` is the usage of Facade, right? class Input extends Facade.

Comment: I did every thing according to your post and got a NotFoundHttpException, also thanks for the link! I am reading it.

Comment: What's the difference between `Input` vs. `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input`? Isn't the first former just the default alias of the latter?

Comment: Important: Make sure the `use` statement comes after the `namespace` statement, or PHP will not recognize it properly.

Comment: Good call @kwoodfriend

Comment: @gabahulk sounds like your issue now is routing and not using the wrong classes.

Comment: @tbuteler check out the facades link in the post.  Facades create a static interface around the object using the application's IoC Container.

Comment: @gabahulk I have modified my post to include your admin route prefix and your auth filter.  I think the route prefix could have been contributing to your NotFoundHttpException (this assumes you tried my code exactly)

Comment: @ChristopherRathgeb I know what a Facade is. My point is that when declared with `use` there is no difference between `Input` with or without the namespace, because they both refer to the Facade.

Comment: @ChristopherRathgeb I've done the modifications that you suggested but now it's not finding the model of Products! I guess this is the right track!

Comment: @tbuteler thank you for your clarification.  I believe I was indeed mistaken on that point.

Comment: @gabahulk can you show the code where you are using the Product Model.  Likely you will just need to use \Product; (unless you have moved your product model into another namespace)

Comment: @ChristopherRathgeb it's in app>controller>admin

Comment: It worked! Thank you! but I have another doubt, how do I redirect to these controllers?

Comment: Redirect::to('admin/products');

Answer (score 1):

Import the `Input` class into the namespace you're using.

```
<?php namespace admin;

use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

    class ProductsController extends \BaseController {
.....
```

Or call `Input` from its namespace:

```
public function index()
{
    $input = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all(); //here is where it finds the error
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But unfortunately id did not work... it returned the error "Class 'Facade' not found" and when I tried to 'use Facade;' it still did not work...

Comment: that isn't the namespace for Facade.  Try `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;`

Comment: Now I have used `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;` and it's still not working :/

Comment: Have you tried calling Input using the second option? `$input = \Input::all();` without a `use` statement?  That may be better suited for your needs in this case.  `Facade` shouldn't be called directly, but included with the `Input` class.

Comment: @Christopher Rathgeb is right.  I apologize.  it is actually, `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`  Sorry!

Comment: As above... Edited answer: `use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`